# How can I get KeyListener to work without maximizing and minimizing the frame?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm trying to program a simple game using Java 1.4.2
It uses two main screens, both of which work using `JPanel`. One of them only has a `MouseListener` and works flawlessly; using the first one, you can open up the second one. The second screen uses a `MouseListener` and a `KeyListener`. The `mousePressed` method works fine. However, the `keyPressed` method doesn't work at first; to get it to work, I have to minimize the window, then reselect it again before it does work.

In the first screen, I was advised to put a `toFront()` command when opening up the second screen; i.e. `secondFrame.toFront()`  However, it gives me an error, saying `No method "toFront()" was found in type "secondFrame"`- even though `secondFrame` extends `JPanel`.

I've heard some information on something called "Key Bindings"; I'm unfamiliar with the topic, but I'd rather solve this problem at its core, without just resorting to a work around. If possible, I'd like to solve this while still using `KeyListener`.

Snippet of code:

```
public TowerDefenceBoard{
    (generic stuff)
    setFocusable (true);
    addKeyListener (this);
    requestFocusInWindow ();
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm very confused by this. What do you mean screens? Are you saying there are two JFrames? and both are part of the same game? Also post the code where you create the non-working keylistener

Comment: each screen is a different JPanel. Visibility between the two is changed via setVisible() to change between them. They're both part of the same game; basically, one is a "main menu" and the other is the "main game". 

I create the keyListener as I create the panel, within the main constructor. I've added it to the original question.

Comment: Ok. IMO using two separate jpanels for this is a big mistake and unnecessary (unless I'm still missing something). Why not use just one JPanel and then draw on it either the menu or the game and switch them? This will eliminate your problem with listeners and be a better coding practice

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `requestFocsInWindow()` on the panel with the `KeyListener`